# Lock SQL table for a period of time

Tags: sql

We are trying to test our new software here which is based on SQL 2005.
We want to  see how it will respond when one of the tables which the  software is using during insert/update gets locked.

Is there a way in SQL 2005 we can simulate this?
so that we can see how we can handle the error on the front end?

Comment: Open a transaction in an interactive connection that requires the table locked?

Answer (score 31):

In SQL Server Management Studio, run this TSQL script (set timeout to whatever suits you)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE table
SET ColumnName = ColumnName

WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00'  -- 2 minutes   hh:mm:ss

-- Run your test while table is locked and delay is counting down

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: while the table is locked for 2 minutes, any other transactions will wait for 2 minutes or they will raise error rightaway?

Comment: that depends what timeout is set on the connection/command issuing the query that's waiting.

Answer (score 5):

Using another session,

1. Do a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`
2. Call `UPDATE table set columnName = columnName`
3. Run your test
4. Verify your results
5. `COMMIT TRAN / ROLLBACK TRAN` the transaction